# How can I repair my USB drive?

Tags: linux, usb, usb-storage

USB drive is in read only state and I can't repair it.

First of all I tried erase it using `dd`:

```
root@yurko-laptop:/home/yurko-laptop# ls -l /dev/disk/by-id | grep usb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Дек 18 23:45 usb-Generic_Flash_Disk_C173828A-0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Дек 18 23:45 usb-Generic_Flash_Disk_C173828A-0:0-part1 -> ../../sdb1
root@yurko-laptop:/home/yurko-laptop# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
dd: запись в «/dev/sdb»: На устройстве кончилось место
8257537+0 записей считано
8257536+0 записей написано
скопировано 4227858432 байта (4,2 GB), 942,633 c, 4,5 MB/c
```

After that I wanted to create new filesystem using `fdisk`:

```
root@yurko-laptop:/home/yurko-laptop# fdisk /dev/sdb
You will not be able to write the partition table.

WARNING: DOS-compatible mode is deprecated. It's strongly recommended to
         switch off the mode (command 'c') and change display units to
         sectors (command 'u').

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sdb: 4227 MB, 4227858432 bytes
4 heads, 63 sectors/track, 32768 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 252 * 512 = 129024 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1              18       32768     4126596    b  W95 FAT32

Command (m for help):
```

`fdisk` showed that the partition still exists and I can't write the partition table.

I tried to delete the existing partition:

```
Command (m for help): d
Selected partition 1

Command (m for help): w

Unable to write /dev/sdb
root@yurko-laptop:/home/yurko-laptop#
```

Why am I not be able to write the partition table?

Does it mean that some hardware failure occurred?

And is it possible to repair the current USB drive?

I've tried to use `hdparm` and it showed that the `readonly` flag is on:

```
root@yurko-laptop:/home/yurko-laptop# hdparm /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  f0 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 26 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 multcount     =  0 (off)
 readonly      =  1 (on)
 readahead     = 256 (on)
 geometry      = 1016/131/62, sectors = 8257536, start = 0
```

Comment: Is it possible this drive is old enough or has had enough use that it is out of write cycles?  A drive will effectively become read-only at that point as well.

Comment: I think yes. In fact it is not my usb and I don't know details about using.
I just tried to repair it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a useful [thread](http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php?topic=103287.15).  They ran `hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb` to try to force the r/w on the drive.

If that fails, I'd try plugging the usb device in while running [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).  You could see if gparted throws any errors about the drive.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help.

hdparm had no any effect.
I tried plug in the usb while gparted running, but I didn't see any changes.

I also tried run 'gparted /dev/sdb', but gparted said "Could not stat device /dev/sdb".

Now fdisk also don't see this usb, so it seems it is time to buy new drive.

But thank you.

Comment: In my case using `hdparm` had no effect, but after it I've changed USB-port and did `hdparm` again and stick was recovered. Thanks for solution!